# After installing ubuntu server error PXE-E53 and PXE-M0F on Fujitsu Primergy S1

Tags: ubuntu, debian, boot, pxe-boot, usb-boot

My server was running on *Debian 11*. I have wanted to reinstall it with a new Debian version and after installation, it wrote me:

```
Please remove installation medium, then press Enter
```

I have removed the disk and pressed Enter. Then it wrote:

```
CLIENT MAC ADDR: ... GUID: ...
PXE-E53: No boot file name received
PXE-M0F: Exiting Intel Boot Agent.
Operating System not found
```

I have found on the internet that there is a problem with disks, but right after the installation?
I can see both of my disks in the *BIOS* - HDD 500GB and SSD 120GB.
Also, *BIOS* is telling me their *"OK"* state.

I tried to install *Ubuntu - ubuntu-22.04.1-live-server-amd64* server to check if there is just some error with *ISO* file from *Debian* but there I am with the same error again.

I am Booting it with USB 16GB

Intel Boot Agent GE v1.3.27

CPU: Intel Xeon X3350 @ 2.83GHz

RAM: 4x 2048MB DDR2-800 ECC Hynix S6

GPU: No graphic card

---

**Also**

When booting Linux installation and continuing with just a console, I can see my disks with their size. Also, the OS is able to install itself on those disks but cannot just boot. Displays that error above.
I also tried Windows Server 2008 and it **CANNOT** find disks. Maybe some installation broke drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So actually, I guess you were right with the RAID. I did not know that
> there is a function in BIOS to turn off the RAID selection. A friend
> just did that and we could easily boot from the BIOS menu now. You can
> reply to this as a new Answer and I will mark it as a solution. Thank
> you very much for your help!

RAID mode allows several hard disk drives to function as one storage area (the array) to provide either data redundancy (backup security) or faster performance (striped reading/writing data from or to the disk drives). note: **Some vendor** *recommends setting the SATA Controller Mode BEFORE installing the operating system*.

Comment: Thank you very much one more time for your patience, explanations, and quick responses!

Answer (score 0):

Answer to these question to yourself:

1.) Do I have properly configured PXE Boot environment on my LAN ?

a.) If I do not have why I do not disable PXE Boot in BIOS ?

b.) If I have a properly configured PXE Boot environment why the menu does not come up where I could choose out the "booting from local disk" option ?

2.) Is the HDD, that has MBR, on the first place in my BIOS ?

a.) If the HDD, that has MBR, is not on the first place in my BIOS why I do not put it on the first place in my BIOS ?

b.) If the HDD, that has MBR, is on the first place in my BIOS, does not boot did I install the OS properly ?

c.) How could I check whether the grub works properly ?

Comment: Sadly I will be in touch with my server on monday. I do not know how to setup PXE lan so I will check on monday. And I think, my HDD and SSD are not even displayed in the bios now and I do  not know why, because they are displayed and usable in linux installation.

Comment: I do not see disks in the boot menu. I can clearly see them using fdisk or lsblk in the installation shell which tells that the Linux is installed on them. They don't want to show up in the boot menu.

Comment: Boot up from a pendrive with live linux. (I assume you know how you do that.) Could you paste here the output of `fdisk -l /dev/sda`

Comment: Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: ST3500418AS
Some other information

Devices
/dev/sda1 2048 4095 2048 1M BIOS boot
/dev/sda2 4096 4198399 4194304 2G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3 4198400 976771071 97257672 463.8G Linux filesystem

Comment: Link to Pastebin with the same data: https://pastebin.com/jiUrijzL

Comment: I expected whether the disk is DOS or GPT labelled. I cannot see in the reports. Could you confirm please that your disk is not GPT labelled ?

Comment: Well, I guess I can confirm it. But actually, I cannot see the label of the disks. The only label is UBUNTU-SERV on my pendrive. Any other label is shown with command `lsblk -o name,mountpoint,label,size,uuid` or command `ls -l /dev/disk/by-label`

Comment: I expect sg like this when you enter the fdisk command. You can see among the raws - Disklabel type: gpt .
`[user@hostname ~]$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 2DB11D88-736A-4A52-ADF2-66DFE1CFCCC3`

Comment: Oh my god you are right, I am sorry... Yes, I can see Disklabel type: gpt

Answer (score 0):

> Oh my god you are right, I am sorry... Yes, I can see Disklabel type:
> gpt

Because of the statement above I need to extend my answer. The most likely reason why your system does not boot because *(disklabel of)* your disk is GPT.

According to your information this is your disk's partition table:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: ST3500418AS
Some other information
 
Devices     Start       End         Sectors     Size        Type
/dev/sda1   2048        4095        2048        1M          BIOS boot
/dev/sda2   4096        4198399     4194304     2G          Linux filesystem
/dev/sda3   4198400     976771071   97257672    463.8G      Linux filesystem
```

Do the following:

1.) Download this [ISO](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) and [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/) it to a pendrive.

2.) Boot up from the pendrive.

3.) Follow the instructions. Repair your GRUB.

4.) When repairing finishes reboot your system from your HDD.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how you meant it, because I cannot see the option "Repair GRUB". I know that you may not mean it like there is this exact option but I cannot see something that would skip the installation and go to the repairs. I can access the console, as I said, so I tried to repair GRUB from this tutorial: [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) but got error. I can say more if you confirm me this is the right step to repair it.

Comment: The first step is clear I think. You download the ISO file. Download Rufus after. Plug a pendrive into your computer and start Rufus. Add the ISO to Rufus and make your bootable pendrive. Now you have a boot-repair-pendrive. Power on your PC and boot from this pendrive. You will see the Repair conversation panel. Follow the instructions. You do not need to change anything so I assume it will be a simple next .. next .. finish.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry... I feel dumb right now. I have read "Download the iso" instead of "THIS" iso... I am working on it now

Comment: I have tried to repair it. I have followed all the steps and I was successful in those steps but still, I am unable to see the disk in the boot menu. I tried to install ubuntu again and then I repaired the GRUB again but ran into the same situation. Also, I went to the console to look at the disk label and it is still GPT (that's my HDD drive I have tried to install ubuntu on) + I have installed in the server second disk - SSD 120GB which has no label. I do not know if it is usable information, so I am just writing it here.

Comment: https://www.fujitsu.com/co/Images/ds-py-tx100-s1.pdf - Is this your server ?
Is it possible that your disk is not configured by your RAID card ? There used to be that HDD need to be added to the RAID card even if you have only one HDD. You should create an array that has one member. I don't know man I am just guessing from now.

Comment: I have reinstalled system quite a lot of times. This was not a first time but it is the first time when I cannot see disks. If that scenario you wrote above is the solution, I guess I have too boot some os and then somehow add the disks to the RAID, right?

Comment: Not seeing a HDD at boot time is something that you need to handle before booting OS. From now it is not about the OS , forget about it. You have sg. basic misconfiguration issue at the very beginning. Your BIOS (or UEFI) must see your HDD. If you have hw. RAID controller it should have a basic CMOS menu. It is responsible for your RAID config before OS boots. Idk take the HDD out from your server and put into a PC to be ensured the HDD is flawless. But I am sure the solution is on the lowest level and not OS level anymore.

Comment: Okay, I guess I need a friend because since I have only a laptop, I am unable to test it. Thanks for your big help and patience. I will give you a break now.

Comment: So I gave HDD to my friend and he placed it into his computer. His computer did not see the HDD so he formated the disk and tomorrow, we will try to place it into my serve so we can know the server sees it now. If the server will see it and I will successfully install Ubuntu server, I will mark your answer as SOLVED.

Comment: So actually, I guess you were right with the RAID. I did not know that there is a function in BIOS to turn off the RAID selection. A friend just did that and we could easily boot from the BIOS menu now. You can reply to this as a new Answer and I will mark it as a solution. Thank you very much for your help!